# Dim / Darken the page with exception of <div> </div>

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have written some jsp/ajax pages and they work as expended. 
I have a need, when particular link is clicked, to dim the page with exception of particular

```
<div id="showAllRooms"> <div>
```

area.(put the page in the "shadows" except of one div)

I am perry geen in JavaScript; could you advise what would be the best approach to this task?

Thank you.

Comment: What does _"dim the page with exception of particular"_ mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a layer (div) that is as large as the body (position:absolute, all corners to postion 0, no padding, no margin)
- keep it hidden (display:none)
- give it a darker backgroundcolor
- give it a higher z-index property
- [otionally] give it an opacity value (opacity:0.5)
- give the div you want to show a higher z-index than the created div
- show the created layer (display:block)

Or use one of the many frameworks for it, like [jquery lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need.  You need put the page in the "shadows" except of one div.

It can be done easily with jQuery ui and it's Model widget.

[preview](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

Comment: could you provide an example?